# Android: Change the style of RadioButtons programmatically

Tags: android, radio-button

how can I change the background image of RadioButtons in selected state. I have used the code for checkBoxes and it works, but for RadioButtons doesnt work. Here is my code snippet:

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(context);
for ( int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++ ){
    // Radiobuttons 
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(context);
    radioButton.setId(i);
    radioButton.setButtonDrawable(myDrawable);
    radioButton.setText(myTxt);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButton, i, layoutParams);

}

this.addView(radioGroup); 

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    StateListDrawable myStates = new StateListDrawable();
    int stateSelected = android.R.attr.state_selected;
    myStates.addState(new int[]{ -stateSelected }, myDrawable2);

    RadioButton  r = (RadioButton) group.getChildAt(checkedId);
    r.setButtonDrawable(myStates);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [state-list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) which defines different background images depending on the state of the widget. You can do this instead of changing the background resource programatically.

A tutorial on this can be found [here](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/55).